# Is it possible to clip a HTML element using an SVG image file as the source?

Tags: html, css, clip

I'm trying to achieve the following effect, this is just done in photoshop with the pattern cut out of the background.

[image: example_clip]

The patterns you see in the left side are cut out of the dark background to display the image that is sitting behind them.

I have the SVG file of that image and was wondering if it is possible, if so how, to clip a solid background to those shapes using the SVG file as the source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by giving the HTML element either a [`mask` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) that references a `<mask>` element in your SVG file or a [`clip-path` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) that references a `<clipPath>` element in your SVG file.

```css
.element {
    /* just because of your example: */
    background-image: url(forest-road.jpg);
    /* use one of these two: */
    clip-path: url(spirograph.svg#myClipPath);
    mask: url(spirograph.svg#myMask);
}
```

```xml
<svg ...>
   <!-- use one of these two: -->
   <clipPath id="myClipPath">
       <!-- shapes, etc., go here -->
   </clipPath>
   <mask id="myMask">
       <!-- shapes, etc., go here -->
   </mask>
</svg>
```

The two CSS features work slightly differently, with masking being newer and more flexible but having some residual gaps in browser support (including needing prefixes). Either way, you'll need to adjust your SVG to be suitable. A `<mask>` should make a pixel white for opaque and black for transparent, with greys being intermediate opacities. On the other hand, a `<clipPath>` defines the region that is visible as the union of a series of shapes.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot! When I apply this it seems to just cut out the whole shape's outer edge rather than cut along the internal path so we can see the lines, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: @PavKR I gather you chose a `<clipPath>`, as that would be odd for a mask. In a clip path, the stroke vs. fill distinction doesn't apply; instead, the entire geometry of every shape is within the path. If your lines are all drawn as strokes on shapes, converting them for `<clipPath>` use might be cumbersome, and a `<mask>` might be easier to build. [This article explains the choice between the two further.](https://css-tricks.com/masking-vs-clipping-use/)

Comment: Thank you - I'll check that article out